# how to know if a valid FirebaseAuth is going to expire soon

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I've a weird behavior in my app related to the firebase database.

I got some unexpected `access denied` when trying to perform some stuff at database... That could be bug in my code but is a pretty simple code. 
I want to ilustrate the sitation with a real scenario, please read the requirements

1- i've only 1 app accessing the database (android)
2- i've only 1 method in the whole app trying to access the specific node which is causing deny of access
3- in my firebase rules the only rule applied to this node is:

```
".read":"auth != null",
".write":"auth != null"
```

4- i DO explicity check `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null` right before calling the method

this is a pseudo snippet of how my code is (i wont pust the real code simple because is too long)

```
public void onResume() {
if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null)
doLogin();
else
checkFirebaseStuff();
}
```

As google doesn't provide any info about why the access was rejected the only possible explanation i found is:

the user was authenticated but long time before, so when it checked on if was still valid, but short time later when the function really ran its token (or some other firebase auth check) was no longer valid, so it caused the access denied

this error doesn't happen a lot, i have 5k daily users and it happens around 20 or 50 times a day, but still shouldn't happen even once
does it make sense? can anyone help me with any aditional info?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I think you can fix this by checking if the user is disconnected from the firebase database, but I'm not really sure if that will affect the Auth too, you can give it a try

```
DatabaseReference connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
        if (connected) {
            Log.d(TAG, "connected");
            //Here you can update your mAuth state
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "not connected");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Listener was cancelled");
    }
});
```